# Проблема в создании списка с автосуммой. Как динамически определять input для выведения суммы?

Tags: input

Доброго времени суток!
Пытаюсь создать макет таблицы в которой будет неопределённое количество строк, но необходимо динамически вычислять сумму 2х input в строке и выводить её в третью. Как создать динамическое определение ID input в строке для дальнейшего манипулирования их значениями?

```html
<body>
        <table border="1">
            <thead>
                <tr><th>№</th>
                    <th>Цена</th>
                    <th>Кол-во</th>
                    <th>Сумма</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" id="num" value="1"> </td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="cena1"> </td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="kol_vo1"> </td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="sum1"> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" id="num" value="2"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="cena2"> </td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="kol_vo2"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="sum2"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
<script>
  ed1=document.getElementById("cena1");
  ed2=document.getElementById("kol_vo1");
  ed1.oninput = function()
  {
    document.getElementById('sum1').value = Number(ed1.value)*Number(ed2.value);
  }
  ed2.oninput = function()
  {
    document.getElementById('sum1').value = Number(ed1.value)*Number(ed2.value);
  }
</script>          
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var count = 0;

function append() {
 count++;
  
  var table = document.getElementById('append');
  var tr = document.createElement('TR');
  
  var td = document.createElement('TD');
  var input_n = document.createElement('INPUT');
  input_n.type = 'text';
  input_n.className = 'num';
  input_n.value = count;
  input_n.readOnly = 'true';
  td.appendChild(input_n);
  tr.appendChild(td);
  
  var td = document.createElement('TD');
  var input_c = document.createElement('INPUT');
  input_c.type = 'text';
  input_c.id = 'cena' + count;
  td.appendChild(input_c);
  tr.appendChild(td);
  
  var td = document.createElement('TD');
  var input_k = document.createElement('INPUT');
  input_k.type = 'text';
  input_k.id = 'kol_vo' + count;
  td.appendChild(input_k);
  tr.appendChild(td);
  
  var td = document.createElement('TD');
  var input_s = document.createElement('INPUT');
  input_s.type = 'text';
  input_s.id = 'sum' + count;
  td.appendChild(input_s);
  tr.appendChild(td);
  
  table.appendChild(tr);
  
  input_k.oninput = function() {
   input_s.value = input_k.value * input_c.value
  };
  
  input_c.oninput = function() {
   input_s.value = input_k.value * input_c.value
  };
}
```

```html
<table border="1" id="append">
  <thead>
    <tr><th>№</th>
      <th>Цена</th>
      <th>Кол-во</th>
      <th>Сумма</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<button onclick="append()">Добавить строку</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Пример работает хорошо!